# What is the size of the largest set of 10-digit phone numbers such that no two numbers in the set are different by only one digit?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem asks for the largest set of 10-digit numbers which are more different than just by one digit. For example, the set canNOT contain both

$1234567890$

and

$1234527890$

as they have only one different digit.

I've been stuck on this problem for a little while as I can't seem to find any way to approach it.

Comment: Subtract the number of $10$ digit numbers with only one different digit from the total number of $10$ digits possible

Comment: Sure, but how do you count the number of 10 digit numbers with only one different digit from all others?

Comment: The first $9$ digits have to be chosen from $10$ digits which is $^{10}C_9$ and the last digit from the chosen $9$ which is $^9C_1$ along with the $10!$ permutations of the $10$ digit number. So you get $10!\cdot^{10}C_9\cdot^9C_1$.

Comment: This is assuming the phone numbers can start with $0$.

Comment: You are allowed repetition of digits within a phone number. For the sake of argument we would allow 0000000000 as a valid phone number. So your method doesn't seem to hold.

Comment: It is better you mention the restrictions or assumptions, if any, in the question so as to remove any ambiguity in the problem. Yes if those are your restrictions then my method does not accommodate all of them. Anyways I would suggest you consider a smaller phone number say a $3-$ digit phone number and work your way up.